# How to sum multiple transactions per account id and then subquery the category of transactions between a certain dollar value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to create a query the gives me the results in grouping the accounts by the total dollar value they have transacted. The table tlists every transaction with columns of `account_id` (which is listed every time someone transacts) and `unit_count` (which is the dollar value they transacted).

The issue is I don't know how to get the the result of total dollar value (unit_count) per account_id before grouping them. The current query I have created results in categorizing the individual transactions, instead of the total value per account:

```
WITH transaction_collapsed (unit_count, transaction_group) AS
(SELECT account_id,
    CASE WHEN unit_count <= 10 then 'less than or equal to 10'
         WHEN unit_count BETWEEN 11 AND 100 THEN 'between 11 and 100'
         WHEN unit_count BETWEEN 101 AND 1000 THEN 'between 101 and 1000'
         WHEN unit_count BETWEEN 1001 AND 10000 THEN 'between 1001 and 10000'
         WHEN unit_count BETWEEN 10001 AND 100000 THEN 'between 10001 and 100000'
         WHEN unit_count BETWEEN 100001 AND 1000000 THEN 'between 100001 and 1000000'
         ELSE 'NA'
    END 
FROM beta.asset_transaction)

SELECT transaction_group, count(*)
FROM transaction_collapsed
GROUP BY transaction_group
ORDER BY transaction_group, count(*) DESC;
```

Query results:

[Screenshot of query results in count categorizing individual transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOqJS.png)

Is there a query I can do before categorizing the `account_id` by `unit_count`?

The account_id is uuid and unit_count is numeric

Comment: mysql or postgresql? they are different

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE asset_transaction;` and post the result into your question. Also, add sample data that could represent the result you're looking for. Use [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0) to create an example.

Comment: @ProGu Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to group twice.  You could add another CTE if you wanted more clarity but it's not really necessary:

```
WITH transaction_collapsed AS (
    SELECT account_id,
    CASE WHEN SUM(unit_count) <= 10 THEN 'less than or equal to 10'
         WHEN SUM(unit_count) BETWEEN 11 AND 100 THEN 'between 11 and 100'
         ...
         ELSE 'NA'
    END AS transaction_group
    FROM beta.asset_transaction
    GROUP BY account_id
)
SELECT transaction_group, count(*)
FROM transaction_collapsed
GROUP BY transaction_group,
ORDER BY transaction_group;
```

You'll notice I took out the second `ORDER BY` column since your transaction groups are (necessarily) distinct, and so we'd never get to it anyway.  Possibly you only meant to `ORDER BY 2 DESC`.

This isn't what you're asking, but you could also remove the repetitiveness of your `CASE` statement, since what you're looking for is very similar to the length of the integer:

```
WITH transaction_collapsed AS (
    SELECT account_id,
    CASE length(GREATEST(SUM(unit_count - 1),0)::TEXT) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'less than or equal to 10'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'between 11 and 100'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'between 101 and 1000'
        ...
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS transaction_group
    FROM beta.asset_transaction
    GROUP BY account_id
)
SELECT transaction_group, count(*)
FROM transaction_collapsed
GROUP BY transaction_group,
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Doing something similar with the 'between x and y' strings could potentially remove the `CASE` altogether, at the cost of making the code a bit harder to read.